# C++, реальные примеры, когда friend классы и функции были бы уместнее, чем иное решение?

Tags: c++

Я задумался над целесообразностью использования в `C++` дружественных функций и классов. Пытался найти внятные примеры, когда это действительно необходимо и дает плюсов больше, чем минусов. Таких примеров мне удалось найти совсем немного.

Может быть, у кого-нибудь есть примеры из жизни, когда `friend` классы и функции были очень удобны?

Comment: Например, `friend` операторы ввода и вывода `<<` и `>>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В С++ модификаторы доступа одинаково работают для всех пользователей класса. Использование `friend` по сути просто делает все кишки класса доступными для дружественной сущности, даже если ей нужно только несколько, и поэтому обычно считается сомнительной практикой. Возможность дать доступ к одной части членов класса для одних пользователей, к другой - для других, а к третьей - третьим (как это делается в языке Еiffel например) из коробки отсутствует. Однако такой высокогранулированный доступ можно обеспечить используя идиому Attorney-Client:

```
class Client 
{
    friend class AttorneyAB;
    private: void A(int a);
    private: void B(float b);
    private: void C(double c);
};

class AttorneyAB
{
    friend class User;
    private: static void callA(Client & c, int a) { c.A(a); } 
    private: static void callB(Client & c, float b) { c.B(b); }
};

class User
{
// User now has access to only Client::A and Client::B through the Attorney.
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Стандартная библиотека часто для реализации той или иной сущности, использует дружественные классы.  Например:

1. класс локализации `locale` определяет класс `facet`, деструктор
   которого защищенный, чтобы все фасеты, наследованные от
   `locale::facet`  и объявляющие класс `locale`  своим другом, могли
   быть уничтожены только данной локализацией.
2. Класс `std::valarray` является другом классов, `std::slice_array,`
   `std::gslice_array, std::mask_array, std::indirect_array`, чьи
   конструкторы являются закрытыми, дабы их экземпляры могли
   создаваться только обьектами `std::valarray`. (Эти классы являются
   вспомогательными  для std::valarray, например для разного
   представления возвращаемого типа `operator[]`).

Для того, чтобы существующая функция(класс) могла  пользоваться закрытыми членами(в том числе, создать или уничтожать обьект, когда конструктор и деструктор не имеют публичный спецификатор доступа), нужно, чтобы она была другом класса...

Answer (score 2):

Начну немного издалека. Вы пишете шаблонный класс имеющий несколько параметров:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, int sz> class MyCoolClass {
};
```

Теперь для этого класса нужно перегрузить операторы +,-,*,/. Только, как то не хочется отдельно перегружать для каждого типа, давайте сделаем перегрузку шаблонной. Я опущу замещения для разных типов:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, int sz> class MyCoolClass {
  public:
    template <class Ti> MyCoolClass operator + (const Ti v) const
    {
         // ....
    }
    // Остальные -,*,/ 
    // ...
};
```

Все пока хорошо. Выражения типа  `MyCoolClass a = MyCoolClass() + 5` работают замечательно. Но, вот выражения `MyCoolClass a = 5 + MyCoolClass()` не работают.
Ладно, значит надо перегрузить операторы глобально. Вот только теперь написать шаблонную перегрузку будет не очень удобно, даже пример приводить неохота. И вот в этом случае дружественная шаблонная функция просто спасение:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, int sz> class MyCoolClass {
  public:
    template <class Ti> MyCoolClass operator + (const Ti v) const
    {
         // ....
    }
    // Остальные -,*,/ 
    // ...
    template <class Ti> friend MyCoolClass operator + (const Ti v, MyCoolClass& v2) 
    {
         // ....
    }
};
```

Обратите внимание, параметры шаблонного класса указывать просто не нужно, что значительно сокращает и упрощает подобные функции. Поэтому в данном случае дружественные функции однозначно полезны. И хотя это только один пример, мне кажется он достаточно веский для существования такого механизма.

Comment: Не считаю, что написать вне класса данный оператор, связан с какими то неудобствами. Совсем наоборот_  такой оператор  обычно лучше  не связывать с классом(с таким подходом вы получите слышком жирный интерфейс). Этот оператор просто может вернуть  `MyCoolClass ()  + T()`.  Кроме мнения у меня возник и вопрос: Причем тут шаблонность?...

Comment: Шаблонность здесь хорошо усугубляет. Напишите такой оператор вне шаблонного класса и увидите разницу. Вам потребуется повторить все параметры шаблона. Насчет жирности здесь речь не шла, только о дружественности.

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что я не писал много шаблонных классов или операторов?  Правильно, речь шла о дружественности, а точнее о ее целесообразности, но вы не понели, что я имел ввиду. Имеется ввиду, что в приведенном вами примере дружественность  совсем не имеет плюса или необходимость, а наоборот... И отметил   отрицательную сторону. И шаблонность тут ничего не усугубляет.

Comment: Во-первых я ничего не говорил о Вашем опыте. Зачем так воспринимать не понимаю, но ладно. Вас смущает жадность шаблона, в ответе указано, что это игнорируется. Какие еще отрицательные стороны? Что касается читаемости кода, простоты Вы считаете это излишним? Больше ненужного текста это лучше?

Comment: я никогда не воспринимаю ничего отрицательного  при обсуждении технических вопросов. Эти обсуждения не зависят от уровня или опыта. Я  лишь отреагировал на ваши слова: "напишите такой оператор ... ", и без мрачных мыслей. И  да,  я считаю, что нет тут  ни пользы, ни необходимости  для дружественности, лучше напечатать несколько символов больше. Не знаю, как вы себя представляете реализацию последнего оператора, но  по мне она тривиальная и однострочная, если  реализован `+=` или  `+`.  Спасибо вам за обсуждение!

Comment: Речь не идет о реализации ее вообще в ответе нет) Поговорим о пользе. Во-первых функция находится внутри класса, хоть и визуальная, но инкапсуляция. Во вторых не будет ошибок в перечислении параметров. Объявление явно короче, визуально явно читабельнее. Этого мало?

Comment: во первых ничего хорошего в том, что он находится внутри класса, во вторых ничего читабельнее в этом нет, в третьих все эти и подобные причины не могут и не должны являться причиной для дружбы . Вы же не будете дружитьс любым, кто вам помог  заполить какой то бланк и  доверять ему ключи от своей квартиры?... В четвертых вы не хотите понять  что и к чему я говорю. Я вам указываю на то, что нет никакой сложной писанины,  связанная со свободным оператором.

Comment: Да. Напоминает, что нет никакой сложности в написании типа итератора вместо auto.