# Как унаследовать вектор обьектов?

Tags: c++, vector

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
class A
{
protected:
    vector<A>vec;
    int переменная_обьекта;   
}

class B:protected A
{
public:
    func()
    {
        vec[num].переменная_обьекта=1;
    }
}
```

В общем кратко описал...Ошибка E0410: не удается получить доступ к защищенному член A::переменная_обьекта.
Я впервые использую вектор обьектов, поэтому не могу понять что к чему, помогите разьяснить и решить проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: так не канает, но проканало, когда в классе A protected на public заменил.
Я как понимаю, оно не пропускает тип вектора?

Comment: `B` может работать с `protected` полями из `A` только если они находятся *в каком-либо объекте типа `B`*.

Comment: Вот по этому скорее всего и не пашет, ведь оказалось, что не допускается не вектор, а переменные. Попробую исправить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спецификатор доступа, указанный при наследовании применяется только при обращении к полям и методам объекта базового класса, который является подобъектом этого объекта. Вектор `vec` является полем подобъекта этого объекта, соответственно доступ к нему есть, однако объекты класса  `A`, которые хранятся в векторе не являются подобъектами этого объекта, соответственно и доступа к их `protected` полям нет.

Comment: то есть ставить модификатор доступа public?

Comment: @ivanuchka007dunduk Или public или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084439/c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-friend-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5/1084447#1084447

Comment: Всё, разобрался, спасибо большое! Всё так просто оказалось)